Mariadb can't enforce charset and collation to clients
I'm trying to force clients to use utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci and uft8mb4.
I tried to add this to all my galera cluster nodes
[mysqld]
...
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
skip-character-set-client-handshake = 1
...

However when I connect with HeidiSQL or mysql-connector-python it never uses it and even says collation-database: latin1_swedish_ci
Using Mariadb 10.11.7 with galera cluster and checking with SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';
Altered my db with
ALTER TABLE XXXX CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
I want to forbid any client to use different values than the server

heidisql has a advanced tab, when connting, maybe you could there add the character set

But the point is to force the clients to use what the server wants

Why not something more modern like uca1400_ai_ci?

usually you can add the character set to the connection string, but heidi doesn't seem to report it so sending a startup sql command seems to be the only option, give it a try

File a bug report with Heidisql.

This is happening when connecting from other clients too like just a simple python script and mysql-connector-python

11.2 has character_set_collations where a 'utf8mb4=uca1400_ai_ci' can be defined.

11.2 isn't stable yet? or should I upgrade? and regardless i just want to make the db enforce the collation on the clients, doesn't matter which one is
